# Vim - Send tab keystroke in keymapping

Tags: vim, tabs

My end goal is trying to make directory navigation in Vim easier, preferably without a plugin.

What I have so for in my `.vimrc`:

```
nmap <m-up> :cd ..<enter>:pwd<enter>
nmap <m-left> :cd -<enter>:pwd<enter>
nmap <m-down> :cd <tab>
```

The first two commands work great.  I can easily go up/back a directory.  The intention of the third command is to quickly get to a set of options that I can tab/arrow-key through to the desired subdirectory.  However, the result is:

```
:cd ^I
```

i.e. it's putting in a tab/ctrl-I char instead of simulating the tab key press, which is the result I want.  I have other commands that use `<esc>` ,`backspace` etc and they all work as desired, but `<tab>` is different.  Any suggestions (besides just hitting tab after my macro)?

Comment: Why all that directory navigation?

Comment: @romainl--It's part of a larger project to use vim as a shell/python environment (kinda like ipython/jupyter but hopefully more powerful).  I'm aware of vimshell/conque, and while they're commendable, they don't quite satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the `wildcharm` option for that:

```
set wildcharm=<C-z>
nnoremap <m-down> :cd <C-z>
```

See `:help wildcharm`.

Comment: Works great, thanks!  And now I know about wildcharm too.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can't "Tab" as you expect it to, because it is interpreting it as part of the vim command, rather than an input for the (bash?) shell. My guess would be to map it to something along the lines of this, if you want to see what is in the working directory:

```
nnoremap <m-down> :!pwd
```

The `no` in `nnoremap` is to prevent any mapping from happening in the reverse direction, kind of a habit that you might want to get into. This will display what is currently in the directory.

Comment: I was afraid of something like that (tabbing not being possible).  "cd" here is a vim command and is shell independent.  Actually cd'ing in a shell via ! will create a new shell process, perform the directory change, and exit without changing the directory within vim.  Thanks for the tip about nnoremap.